# Is std::sqrt the same as sqrt in C++

Tags: c++, sqrt

I'm very new to C++, I have this piece of code, the code looks like this:

```
D = (sum_B / double(E))*std::sqrt(E)
```

Can someone interpret it into a math formula or something easy to understand, I'm not sure what is this `std::sqrt` , wondering if it is the same with my formula:

```
A = sum(B*C)/sum(B)
D = A * sqrt(E)
```

(A/B/C/D/E represent different columns in my dataset)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt

Comment: How is `sum_B` defined?

Comment: Depends on what `sqrt` is. The C-function included from `math.h`? Then it's most likely the same as `std::sqrt`. Wether the result is the same is entirely different question, because there many variables and functions we can't see or know about.

Comment: `std::sqrt()` is a square root calculation, you can find it in the header `cmath` (basically `math.h` wrapped in namespace `std`). You may take a look at [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt).

Comment: In C++ types snd `#include` lines and all that are rather important, so it is best to include a [mcve] code with a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

I doesn't look like the same formula as in the `A = sum(B*C)/sum(B)` you're using `C` column which is not existent in your first formula `D = (sum_B / double(E))*std::sqrt(E)`

As for your primary question "sqrt" is simply an acronym of "square root".

The definition of standard std::sqrt is available under [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt).

> std::sqrt(arg) - computes the square root of arg

Comment: You are linking to the wrong  version in the documentation. There is nothing about complex numbers here. You should have linked against [this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) instead.

Comment: @Fareanor Yor're totally right, thanks for correction

Comment: @Fareanor: Since the question lacks actual code, we don't know the actual type of `E`. But I agree that it can't be complex, since `std::complex<double>` cannot be casted to `double`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first formula is essentially this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you `#include <cmath>` then `std::sqrt` becomes available for use. Don't rely on it being implicitly included and equally, don't rely on `sqrt` being available, in case someone else has defined `sqrt` for whatever reason.

Your formula can be simplified a little to

```
D = sum_B / std::sqrt(E);
```

In any case, you need to check that `E` is positive.